# How can I integrate ipfs with substrate node

Tags: pallet

I am trying to integrate ipfs in substrate-node-template, I came across https://github.com/rs-ipfs/substrate/tree/offchain_ipfs/bin/node-template, when I am trying to build it , getting many build error, basically they are because of different version, As the last code updated in repo is 2years ago.
So I tried to use with substrate version 3.0.0, but there also I found some version conflict.
After fixing this, I found another error such as "error: unresolved imports sp_core::offchain::IpfsRequest"
When i checked in sp-core crates.io https://docs.rs/sp-core/4.0.0/sp_core/offchain/index.html, there is no such IpfsRequest , IpfsResponse modules present.

Can anyone help for this.

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on a fork of this repo. To update to V3, I ended up just rebuilding the entire repo on top of the substrate master branch. Most of it is encapsulated here: https://github.com/iridium-labs/substrate/commit/7a1c1c89857e28b3a1dbd3a56ca2c8d433ce233d

Comment: Could you provide a tutorial on how to use it with an existing project?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the main `offchain::ipfs` fork has stalled for a bit.
See the readme on this branch of the repo:

https://github.com/rs-ipfs/substrate/tree/offchain_ipfs

It seems there are two other well-maintained forks you can use instead.

Comment: As the author of the iridium-labs/substrate fork, significant updates have been added to a different branch, available here: https://github.com/iridium-labs/substrate/tree/iris

Comment: My apologies for that, judged based on time on master. I'll update